# Clear button for my canvas in JPanel when drawing shapes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am drawing shapes and the shapes store into an arraylist.
When I hit clear, all the shapes clear out of the arraylist except for the last one I have drawn.

I even did

```
Arraylist list = new Arraylist();
list.clear();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Size is: " + list.size());
```

just to prove the size was 0 and a similar test to make sure the last added object was added into the array list. What could be the possible reasons for this?

Comment: That would imply that the list is indeed empty however your rendering logic either has not been called afterward or has an error. Could you post how they are being painted to the screen?

Comment: Probably you need to call repaint() again.

Comment: I did. Still leaves the last guy on the screen.

Comment: I'd post my code, but I have to avoid plagiarism matchup through university. I draw on screen, that rectangle stores to array. This rectangle is stored on mouse release. When I released, the message box updates and tells me current size and proves the list has incremented.

Answer (score 2):

call the repaint() method in the event handler of the clear button.

```
list.clear();
repaint();
```

it will refresh your canvas.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I added repaint. Still same error.

Comment: remove the canvas from the parent window using the remove() method.and add a new canvas.

Answer (score 2):

```
Arraylist list = new Arraylist();
list.clear();
```

Well, that doesn't do anything because all did was create a local variable which is empty to begin with and then clear the empty List. Your painting code will still be referencing the instance variable from your class. Your code should just be:

```
//Arraylist list = new Arraylist();
list.clear();
```

Comment: The arraylist is filled as the user draws rectangles

Comment: @KnowledgeGeek,  `That is what my code does...` - that is not what you posted!!! Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem if you want help. We are not mind readers and we can't guess what you are doing.